# Python: Integral and funcion nested in another integral using scipy quad

Tags: python, scipy, probability, numeric, stochastic-process

I have managed to write a few lines of code using scipy.integrate.quad for my stochastic process class

I have the Markov transition function for standard Brownian motion

```
import numpy as np
def p(x,t):
    return (1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*t))*np.exp(-x**2/(2*t))
```

But I want to compute the following that I am going to write in code that would not work. I write it like this so we can understand the problem without the use of latex.

```
 from scipy.integrate import quad
 integral = quad(quad(p(y-x),1,np.inf)*p(x,1),1,np.inf)
```

You probably noticed that the problem is the bivariate thing going on in the inner integral. I did the following but am unsure of it:

```
p_xy = lambda y,x: p(y-x,1)
inner = lambda x : quad(p_xy,1,np.inf,args = (x,))[0]
outer = lambda x: inner(x)*p(x,1)
integral = quad(outer,1,np.inf)[0]
```

I then get

```
 0.10806767286289147
```

I love Python and its lambda functions but seem to not be sure about this. What are your thoughts? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is there a question here? It seems you're just asking for opinions.

Comment: You aren't sure about the answer or about the most efficient way? To address the former, try using some known benchmark analytical integral.

Comment: I guess that I'm ashamed to be so direct as to ask, "Teacher, is my answer correct?" . I guess that would pretty much sum it up. Do you think the value I got is correct?

Comment: As far as efficiency goes, I'm happy with this. I actually tried Sympy at first. It seemed to not be able to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the type of integral you wish to perform, bivariate integrals, SciPy has [dedicated routines](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html#general-multiple-integration-dblquad-tplquad-nquad).

The advantage is that these routines handle complex boundaries more easily (were the bounds depend on the other coordinate, for instance).

I rewrote your example as:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import nquad

def p(x,t):
    return (1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*t))*np.exp(-x**2/(2*t))

def integrand(x, y):
    return p(y-x, 1)*p(x, 1)

integral = nquad(integrand, ((1, np.inf), (1, np.inf)))

print(integral[0])
```

which prints out the same result. I believe that the code above is easier to read as the integrand is written explicitly as a function of the two variables.

Comment: Thank you so much for this valuable learning experience. I like this explanation and additional example a lot!